# ':' expected.ts(1005) how to fix

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

saw number of issues tried suggestions, so far no luck. Currently
using vsc version 1.76.2, Node 16.14.2 ts version 4.6.4 from ng version command

barChartData is

```
  public barChartData: ChartData<'bar'> = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [],
        // data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        // backgroundColor: ['#012169', '#0073cf', '#646464', '#012169', '#0073cf', '#646464', '#012169'],
        // hoverBackgroundColor: ['#8090b4', '#80b9e7', '#919191', '#8090b4', '#80b9e7', '#919191', '#8090b4'],
      },
    ]
  };
```

it is part of Chart.js v 3.9.1 the labels can be undefined

in vsc a popup shows

```
(property) ChartData<"bar", number[], unknown>.labels?: unknown[] | undefined
```

the event handler is where the error is happening:

```
  public chartClicked(e: any): void {
    this.barChartData.labels?[0];

    console.log(e);
  }
```

I get an error of

```
':' expected.ts(1005)
```

and when trying to build from ng serve

```
./src/app/components/test03/test03.component.ts:127:69 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (127:69)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
 * ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     }
|     chartClicked(e) {
>         console.log(this.barChartData.labels ? [e.active[0].index] : );
|         console.log(e);
|     }

Error: src/app/components/test03/test03.component.ts:135:61 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

135     console.log(this.barChartData.labels?[e.active[0].index]);
                                                                ~




× Failed to compile.
```

how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?.` is what you probably meant to use (called [optional chaining [MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)). You are missing the `.`

The reason for the error is because `?` in js (and thus typescript) is a [conditional (ternary) operator [MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It expects `:` because that is the syntax of the ternary operator.

```js
let checkMe = true;
console.log(checkMe ? "truthyCase" : "falsyCase");
// outputs "truthyCase"
```

The `?` question mark is in your code as seen in the error:

```js
Error: src/app/components/test03/test03.component.ts:135:61 - error TS1005: ':' expected.
                                            v
135     console.log(this.barChartData.labels?[e.active[0].index]);
                                            ^                   ~
```

and because you only put `?` and not `?.`, it interprets that as the ternary operator and not the optional chaining operator.

Answer (score 6):

To use the optional chaining operator with brackets, you still have to add a dot after the question mark:

```js
this.barChartData.labels?.[0];
```

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#optional_chaining_with_expressions)

Answer (score 2):

[You need a `.` to use optional chaining with arrays.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#optional_chaining_with_expressions) Change `this.barChartData.labels?[0];` to `this.barChartData.labels?.[0];`